# shortening a URL string programmatically

Tags: java, string, onclick, android-edittext

I have an `EditText` in my app which users can enter a youtube url.

Example url is like following:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gXrWv6zlg8s
```

When i grab the text and make it to a string, i only need the last chars like **gXrWv6zlg8s**

How can i shorten the string value to only this charset?

```
final EditText url = findViewById(R.id.url);
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String a;
            a = url.getText().toString().trim();}
}
```

Thanks for advice.

Comment: thanks @UnholySheep would write this a seperate method and pass in (a)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the trick :

```
a = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("=") + 1);
```

Comment: do i still use a the url = getText first @Nicholas?

Comment: You will need to assign it to `a`, I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: thanks mate i will mark yours as the answer as you were actaully first

Comment: cant exept for another 5 mins

Answer (score 4):

```
String url= "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gXrWv6zlg8s";
System.out.println(url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("=") + 1));
```

Comment: Unsafe -> Assumes a parameter is always present and in that index location.

Answer (score 3):

Safe answer:

```
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gXrWv6zlg8s");
    if(uri.getQueryParameterNames().contains("v"))
    Log.d(DEBUG,uri.getQueryParameter("v"));
```

Add a "throw videoCodeMissingException" else.

EDIT:

```
    String myUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gXrWv6zlg8s";
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(myUrl);
    if (uri.getQueryParameterNames().contains("v")) {
        Log.d(DEBUG, uri.getQueryParameter("v"));
    } else {
        throw new NoVideoParameterFoundException(myUrl);
    }

private class NoVideoParameterFoundException extends Exception{
        public NoVideoParameterFoundException(String message) {
            super(message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: can u explain this please, would it not be easier to use the methods below?

Comment: Not entirely sure why the downvote.
This is the only method that doesn't assume the string always has the parameter key "v" and also a value for v.
If Youtube added another parameter...the other suggested methods may fail...or say if the video is unavailable and you get some other string...it may even throw a null/out of bounds exception.

Comment: not sure my self pal? i will up mark it for you ;-) thanks for the help

Comment: @Jcov :: absolutely the best answer (upvote). This is the only answer which gives the user the control to pick the parameter and get the value to that parameter. Whoever downvoted it should give an explanation

Comment: brill thanks Jcov. people soon changed minds about downvoting you haha

Comment: could you upvote my question please as someone down voted it.. i assume becuse i marked yours as right lol